# Popen subprocess does not exit when stdin includes unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, popen, python-unicode

I am executing a subprocess using `Popen` and feeding it input as follows (using Python 2.7.4):

```
env = dict(os.environ)
env['LC_ALL'] = 'en_US.UTF-8'
args = ['chasen', '-i u', '-F"%m "']
process = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, env=env)
out, err = process.communicate(input=string)
```

Adding the entry to the environment it is executed with is necessary because the input string includes Japanese characters, and when the script is not executed from the command line (in my case being called by Apache), Python cannot guess the encoding.

This setup has worked fine for me with other commands, however now I'm using `chasen` (a Japanese tokenizer), whenever I send it unicode characters the subprocess does not return, and it just sits there with the Python script chewing up memory. This seems like an encoding problem, but I thought I had would have sorted this out by specifying the encoding with the `LC_ALL` environment variable.

Edit: Extra weirdness as follows... I don't get this problem when executing the Python script from the command line with the notable exception of the '。' character. For some reason this causes the strangeness from `chasen` also.

Comment: Python 2.x, or 3.x? (When you're dealing with Unicode problems, the answer is almost always very different between the two.)

Comment: Actually, better to specify the _exact_ version, because there's a major rewrite of `communicate` in 3.2, and some important bug fixes in 2.7.x and 3.1.x versions as well…

Comment: His program has the described symptom both in 2.7.4 and in 3.3.1.  It happens only when the input contains wide UTF-8 characters. It has something to do with `chasen`, as when replacing that with `cat`, it works OK.  But, from the command line, `chasen` also works OK.

Comment: @nickie: By "wide UTF-8" you mean not 1 byte, not within the BMP, or something different?

Comment: @abarnert: I guess, not any of these.  It works for u"hello world" (1 byte), it works for u"γεια χαρά" (Greek, 2 byte), and it does not work for u"悪妻は百年の不作。" (Japanese, 2 or 3 byte --- I've no clue about the UTF encoding of Japanese).

Comment: @nickie: Well, those are all 3-byte in UTF-8, but all within the BMP, which is weird, to say the least. If you just run `echo "悪妻は百年の不作。" | chasen -i u '-F"%m "'` on the shell, does that work properly?

Comment: @abarnert: I'm using Python 2.7.4

Comment: @abarnert: Yes.  The output is `"悪妻 ""は ""百 ""年 ""の ""不作 ""。 "`. (I guess humble coffee didn't intend the quotes to come out like this, but never mind.)  It's a Python thing, but if you replace `chasen` with `cat` in the `Popen` call, it works fine.

Comment: @abernert: I confirm what humble coffee just wrote; it's the '。'  character (apparently E3 80 82).  Without it, it works OK.

Comment: Yep, just running that on the command line works fine, but when I call it from the Python script it fails. In this case it's specifically the '。' character that is the problem (see added information to the post). Removing that character fixes the problem. However when the Python script is called via Apache, then the problem is with any Japanese characters, removing that character does not fix it.

Comment: @abarnert: You want to get rid of those extra single quotes, that was what was causing the extra quotes in the output: `echo "悪妻は百年の不作。" | chasen -i u -F"%m "`

Comment: Well, if you get the problem with even one character just running from the shell, that's enough to repro it without Python, Apache, and all the other stuff. And, once you've got a repro case, fixing it is probably more important than trying to characterize exactly when it shows up. So… any chance you have a broken build, old/known-buggy version, etc., of chasen?

Comment: When I mean from the shell, I mean running the Python script (that calls chasen) from the shell. So I have not seen this problem with just chasen on its own from the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in chasen. When run through Python, you can see the following syscalls it issues:

```
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
read(0, "", 4096)                       = 0
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
read(0, "", 4096)                       = 0
```

i.e. it does not correctly handle [EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file). To fix this, simply affix a newline (`'\n'`) to your Python string, like this:

```
# coding: utf-8
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

string = u"悪妻は百年の不作。"

env = dict(os.environ)
env['LC_ALL'] = 'en_US.UTF-8'
args = ['chasen', '-i u', '-F"%m "']
process = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, env=env)
out, err = process.communicate(input=(string + u'\n').encode('utf-8'))

print(out)
```

Comment: Perfect, that does indeed fix it. Thanks!